# Populate wxPython Grid from DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, wxpython

I am building a GUI to view and update tables in mySQL. I am fetching the results, loading them into a pandas DataFrame, and then writing them out to the Grid.

From mySQL to the DataFrame, it is almost instant. The problem is it takes some time to loop each value and write them to grid. I am trying to find a faster way to populate the grid. I have looked into using a GridTableBase class, but I did not really understand it as I am not very experienced in Python.

To load the DataFrame, I am using:

```
db_con = MySQLdb.connect(user=user_id,password=pw,database=db_name,host=host_id,charset='utf8')
cursor = db_con.cursor()
```

To populate the wxPython Grid: (This throws errors on same tables for some reason)

```
#Populate Grid
for i in range(len(self.df_data.index)):
    for j in range(len(self.df_data.columns)):
         self.data_grid.SetCellValue(i,j,self.df_data.iat[i,j])

UPDATE: I have used the GridTableBase. The result is not much faster
```